# Import an entire directory of json files with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I usually don't have to deal with external files but now I have to automate a process to import entire directories of JSON files.  All the files have the same structure.  I'm using the following sql to import a single file:

```
    DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET 
    (BULK 'R:\data\ETL\json\3781.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
    AS j

    If (ISJSON(@JSON)=1)

    Select * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.api.events')
    with   (FixtureID int '$.fixture_id',
            EventDate datetime2 '$.event_date',
            Venue nvarchar(50) '$.venue',
            CityName nvarchar(20) '$.region.city_name',
            EventID tinyint '$.region.event_id'
    )
```

But is there an easy way to import an entire directory of similar files ?  Or do I have to create a sp in which I list all the files of a directory (using something like xp_dirtree) and loop through them to import the whole batch ?

Comment: I would use PowerShell rather than T-SQL. I'll provide an example if you elaborate more on "....etc".

Comment: @Dan Guzman, I've updated the code.  I was in the process of testing the content of the json files, so nothing much there.

Comment: I agree on powershell - this is really an "external" function that shouldn't be done inside T-SQL. Powershellequally lightweight as T-SQL (no compile required)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a PowerShell example ETL script that imports all json files in the specified directory into a relational database table using a parameterized `INSERT` query. The script reads the file contents from each file and uses [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to convert the json string into a custom object that exposes the parsed values as properties, making it easy to extract the values.

This example can be extended according to your needs, such as additional validation and transformation, handle missing fields, using [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) for bulk inserts, etc.

Example DDL for target table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(
     FixtureID int
    ,EventDate datetime2
    ,Venue nvarchar(50)
    ,CityName nvarchar(20)
    ,EventID tinyint
);
```

PS script:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=JsonImportExample"

Function Insert-YourTable($json) {
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $insertQuery = @"
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(
     FixtureID
    ,EventDate
    ,Venue
    ,CityName
    ,EventID
)
VALUES(
     @FixtureID
    ,@EventDate
    ,@Venue
    ,@CityName
    ,@EventID
);
"@
    $insertCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($insertQuery, $connection)
    [void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FixtureID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value = $json.api.events.fixture_id)
    [void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EventDate", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime2).Value = $json.api.events.event_date)
    [void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Venue", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 50).Value = $json.api.events.venue)
    [void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CityName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 20).Value = $json.api.events.region.city_name)
    [void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EventID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::TinyInt).Value = $json.api.events.region.event_id)
    $connection.Open()
    [void]$insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
}

# ############
# ### MAIN ###
# ############

try {

    $jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\JsonFiles\*.json"

    foreach ($jsonFile in $jsonFiles) {

        Write-Host "Importing $($jsonFile.FullName)..."
        try {
            $json = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($jsonFile.FullName) | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
        catch [System.ArgumentException]{
            Write-Host "Error parsing json. File ignored" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        Insert-YourTable -json $json

    }

}
catch {
    throw    
}
```

**EDIT:**

In cases where the source json value is null, you can use null coalescing to substute `DbNull.Value` (or some other value) using a technique like:

```
[void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FixtureID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).Value = if($json.api.events.fixture_id -eq $null) {[DbNull]::Value} else {$json.api.events.fixture_id} )
[void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EventDate", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime2).Value = if($json.api.events.event_date -eq $null) {[DbNull]::Value} else {$json.api.events.event_date} )
[void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Venue", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 50).Value = if($json.api.events.venue -eq $null) {[DbNull]::Value} else {$json.api.events.venue} )
[void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CityName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 20).Value = if($json.api.events.region.city_name -eq $null) {[DbNull]::Value} else {$json.api.events.region.city_name} )
[void]($insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EventID", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::TinyInt).Value = if($json.api.events.region.event_id) {[DbNull]::Value} else {$json.api.events.region.event_id} )
```

Comment: I managed to make it run and it works fine most of the time (many thanks) but I sometimes have null values in my JSON files (for a particular INT field) and I then get an error because of it.  I tried adding | OUT-NULL at the end of the insert commands but still get an error.  Any way to fix that ?

Comment: @CrnaKrv, I added a null coalescing example to my answer.

Comment: I wish there was a way to do it without writing that much extra code but this does the job in the end.  Thx.